# Queston about big O notation

Tags: time, big-o, cpu, notation

Let's say I have getNumber() return me a integer stored in a class that I instantiated in main.

```
public int getNumber()
{
  return number;
}
```

Would the above code take O(1) and would the below code take O(2)? Or am I misunderstanding how O notation works in terms of CPU cycles to complete a operation?

```
public int getNumber()
{
  int myNumber = number;
  return myNumber;
}
```

So rephrasing my question, would returning an object's variable in one line be the same performance-wise as declaring another variable to hold that object's variable and then returning it in another line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big-O notation isn't about counting the exact number of CPU cycles, but about counting orders of magnitude in relation to some varying size (e.g., the length of an input). Here, both functions have a constant runtime which is not dependent on any additional size, and thus are both O(1).

(By the way, in any real-world scenario, I'd expect a decent compiler to inline the `int myNumber = number` line, and make the two function declarations essentially identical)

Answer (score 1):

First things first: The big O notation is a classification on *functions*, the symbol `O(n)` stands for the *set* of all functions from ℝ to ℝ that grow at most as fast/much as any positive multiple of the function *f(n) = n*.

This technical introduction (which has been narrowed down to this context) was necessary to make it clear that the big O notation is used to tell how fast/much a function grows.
And in doing so, we don't consider the exact multiple: *10n*, *5n* and *20n* all are `O(n)` because they are a multiple of the function `n`.
While things like `O(5n)` are a bit of an abuse of notation (where we have multiple symbols denote the same set as `O(n)`) they are frequently used.

The big O notation need a function to measure, in the theory of computational complexity the two main functions measures are the *time complexity* and *the space complexity*.

Time complexity is a function that measure the number of *steps* taken by an algorithm to produce its output as a function of the *length* of the *encoding* of its input (i.e. the input `10` as length 2, two digits).
There is an hidden gotcha here, what is a *step*?
The step is a step only when given a *computational model*, in other words one first need to establish how computations are done, what steps are possible.
This is seldom made clear or stated explicitly in the literature, I don't know why.

For example, the instruction `a = b + c` is often regarded as a single step, this is because the computational model used is the high-level language in which the program is written.
However there are contexts where `a = b + c` is not considered a single step, one such context is the *bit-complexity*, a model that consider each operation on every bit a single step (thus that instruction would be `O(m)` where `m` is the length, in bit, of the numbers).

In you example, the first implementation has complexity `O(1)` since there is only a single statement in the function body.
The second has two statements, one of which is a variable initialization. It's up to the computational model to set if variables initialised from constant expressions (beware if they take their values from something that must be computed at runtime) count as a step or not.
You can safely assume they always do since they add at most an `O(1)` to the total cost which will be dominated by any code in the function body (unless the function body has only variable initilisations).
So the second function has cost `O(2)` (with abuse of notation) but `O(2) = O(1)` by definition.

This should clarify the misunderstanding about CPU cycles. When using an high-level language to describe an algorithm we are not concerned with CPU cycles, our computation model is a machine that understand that high-level language directly! This must be the case as we cannot know how it will be translated to assembly instructions so we cannot count the CPU cycles.
Remember *time* complexity is *not* about time as we measure it, it is about a number of *steps* not about a number of elapsed ticks.
When using an high-level language the computational model implied is the one where each statement of the language is a step.

One more note of caution: time complexity combined with big O notation cannot be used to measure performance too closely.  An `O(n^2)` with a small constant is better than an `O(n)` with a constant so huge it will always be greater than any possible value of `n` for any real instantiation of the problem.
But that's a nuisance (mostly found on numerical methods), for a general overview constants can be dropped. And indeed it is a great tool as otherwise the analysis would be too complex.